# NIntegrate with list gives weird results

Tags: numerical-integration

Suppose I defined list or matrix with numericQ with some purpose,

```
AA[kx_?NumericQ, ky_?NumericQ] := {{kx^.5, 2 ky^2}, {kx^2, ky^2}},
```

and I want to numerically integrate this, such as,

```
NIntegrate[AA[qx, qy][[2,2]], {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 2}].
```

This manages to give right result with error,

> Part::partd: Part specification AA[qx,qy][[2,2]] is longer than depth of object. >>

This is the first thing I can't understand because there seems to be no syntax error. Next, suppose I mistyped the above integration like,

```
NIntegrate[AA[qx, qy][[2]], {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 2}].
```

Even though AA[qx, qy][[2]] is List, NIntegrate gives *number*. That's the second I don't understand. Because of error I couldn't trust the result in research level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re: why, since you specify `_?NumericQ` when `NIntegrate` makes its first attempt at symbolic evaluation `AA` returns unevaluated, thus the `Part` request fails.

here is another way to work around the problem:

```
AA[kx_?NumericQ, ky_?NumericQ, i_, j_] :=
    {{kx^.5, 2 ky^2}, {kx^2, ky^2}}[[i, j]];
NIntegrate[AA[qx, qy, 2, 2], {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 2}]
```

> 26.6667

as to the even stranger seeming second result, the symbolic expression `AA[qx,qy]` has *first level* parts which are the arguments.  `AA[qx,qy][[2]]` -> `qy`  so then your integral is

```
  NIntegrate[qy, {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 2}]
```

> 20.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed). Indexed works like [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part), but only extracts the part when the argument is a list. So:

```
NIntegrate[
    Indexed[AA[qx,qy], {2,2}],
    {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 2}
]
```

> 26.6667

Comment: + .. note to document writers, why does neither `Part` nor `Extract` say "see also" `Indexed` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
AA[kx_, ky_] := {{kx^.5, 2 ky^2}, {kx^2, ky^2}};
NIntegrate[AA[qx, qy][[2, 2]], {qx, 0, 10}, {qy, 0, 2}]

(*  26.7  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Yeah. I know the answer but what I don't get it is what 's wrong with NumericQ. At the first time, I think NumericQ and NIntegrate would work well but it did not.